# Multiplying strings/arrays and global arrays

Tags: c++

so I was doing this  code in which you scan a number then that number pairs of numerical strings example

5

5 5

6 6

7 7

8 8

and the program should then output

25
36
49
64
81

which is the first number *the second number

but mine outputs

25

61  //25+36

110  //110+49

174   //110+64

the reason is that in my code I keep each multiplication in an array called arr2 which I declared globally and since I don't reset all values back to 0 it keeps adding up but the problem is don't know how to reset all of its values back to 0 since when I tried it would not let me

code in which I did not try to reset the array which works the way I already mentioned

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;
typedef long double ld;
typedef vector<long long> vi;
typedef pair<long long, long long> pi;
typedef vector<pi> vpi;

#define FOR(i, a, b) for (ll i = ll(a); i < ll(b); i++)
#define ROF(i, a, b) for (ll i = ll(a); i >= ll(b); i--)
#define f first
#define s second
#define pb emplace_back
#define mp make_pair
#define SQ(a) (a) * (a)
#define all(a) (a).begin(), (a).end()
int arr[9999];

int multiply(string a, string b, int n)
{
    int r = 0, j = 0;
    int x = int(b[0] - 48);
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int mult = 0, y = int(a[i] - 48);
        mult = x * y + r;

        arr[j] = mult % 10;
        r = (mult - mult % 10) / 10;
        j++;
    }
    if (r != 0) {
        arr[j] = r;
        return n + 1;
    }
    else {
        return n;
    }
}
int arr2[9999] = { 0 }, u = 0; //here I declared it
int suma(int w, int f)
{

    int b[w];
    int r = 0;
    int s = 0, j = 0;
    w = w + f;
    for (int i = f; i < w; i++) {
        s = arr2[i] + arr[i - f] + r;
        arr2[i] = s % 10;
        r = (s - s % 10) / 10;
        j++;
    }
    if (r != 0) {
        if (w >= u) {
            arr2[j] = r;
            j++;
        }
        else {
            while (r != 0) {
                s = arr2[j] + arr[j - f] + r;
                arr2[j] = s % 10;
                r = (s - s % 10) / 10;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    int u = max({ w, u, j });
    return u;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    int as;
    cin >> as;
    for (int cfg = 0; cfg < as; cfg++) {
        int w, k = 0, l = 0;
        string a, b, c;
        cin >> a >> b;
        reverse(b.begin(), b.end());
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
            c = b[i];
            w = multiply(a, c, a.length());
            k = suma(w, i);
            l = max(k, l);
        }

        int narr[l];
        narr[l] = { 0 };
        copy(arr2 + 0, arr2 + l, narr);
        int n = sizeof(narr) / sizeof(narr[0]);
        reverse(narr, narr + n);
        int qw = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (narr[i] != 0) {
                qw = 1;
            }
            if (qw == 1) {
                cout << narr[i];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code in which I tried but gives me an error:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;
typedef long double ld;
typedef vector<long long> vi;
typedef pair<long long, long long> pi;
typedef vector<pi> vpi;

#define FOR(i, a, b) for (ll i = ll(a); i < ll(b); i++)
#define ROF(i, a, b) for (ll i = ll(a); i >= ll(b); i--)
#define f first
#define s second
#define pb emplace_back
#define mp make_pair
#define SQ(a) (a) * (a)
#define all(a) (a).begin(), (a).end()
int arr[9999];

int multiply(string a, string b, int n)
{
    int r = 0, j = 0;
    int x = int(b[0] - 48);
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int mult = 0, y = int(a[i] - 48);
        mult = x * y + r;

        arr[j] = mult % 10;
        r = (mult - mult % 10) / 10;
        j++;
    }
    if (r != 0) {
        arr[j] = r;
        return n + 1;
    }
    else {
        return n;
    }
}
int arr2[9999] = { 0 }, u = 0; //here I declared it
int suma(int w, int f)
{

    int b[w];
    int r = 0;
    int s = 0, j = 0;
    w = w + f;
    for (int i = f; i < w; i++) {
        s = arr2[i] + arr[i - f] + r;
        arr2[i] = s % 10;
        r = (s - s % 10) / 10;
        j++;
    }
    if (r != 0) {
        if (w >= u) {
            arr2[j] = r;
            j++;
        }
        else {
            while (r != 0) {
                s = arr2[j] + arr[j - f] + r;
                arr2[j] = s % 10;
                r = (s - s % 10) / 10;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    int u = max({ w, u, j });
    return u;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    int as;
    cin >> as;
    for (int cfg = 0; cfg < as; cfg++) {
        arr2[9999] = { 0 }; //here I try to set all the values back to 0
        int w, k = 0, l = 0;
        string a, b, c;
        cin >> a >> b;
        reverse(b.begin(), b.end());
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
            c = b[i];
            w = multiply(a, c, a.length());
            k = suma(w, i);
            l = max(k, l);
        }

        int narr[l];
        narr[l] = { 0 };
        copy(arr2 + 0, arr2 + l, narr);
        int n = sizeof(narr) / sizeof(narr[0]);
        reverse(narr, narr + n);
        int qw = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (narr[i] != 0) {
                qw = 1;
            }
            if (qw == 1) {
                cout << narr[i];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Format!Style:
C++ online code formatter © 2014 by KrzaQ

Powered by vibe.d, the D language and clang-format
```

So the question would be if is there any way to reset all the values to 0 or any other way to solve the problem if you can you could submit a code that works if not just tell me how to fix it,thank you

Comment: Your code is unreadable with all of those crazy macros.

Comment: You may find your programs easier to debug if you don't go to such lengths to encrypt the code. II hope you get a good answer, but I've got better things to do with my time than unscramble code in order to debug it.

Comment: "competitive programming" is teaching you how to write garbage. Btw, you have undefined behavior here `int narr[l]; narr[l]={0};`

Comment: I wish they would use "competitive debugging".  It seems a lot like to write the obfuscated code, and then ask stackoverflow to debug it if something goes wrong.

Comment: Ugh - start with clean code, get it working, then obfuscate it.  That looks like puke on my screen.

Comment: [Is this what your code is supposed to do?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38eda4fc126cfc42)

Answer (score 0):

To clear the `arr` array, you can use `memset` like:

```
memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);
```